# Battery not charging after installing Ubuntu 19

Tags: power-management, laptop, asus, battery, charging

I dual booted my Windows 10 laptop with Ubuntu 19.10 and immediately after installation, when I restarted my laptop I detected that the laptop is not charging even though the battery is detected.
Even in Windows 10, it is the same issue. The message is

> Connected but not charging

I am assuming the issue is a software issue as it happened right after Ubuntu installation. Also, when the computer switched on after restart, there was some diagnostic scan prompt (to fix some potential errors) which I chose to ignore and now I can't get that screen back (maybe it would solve the problem?)

I am using Asus ROG Strix Scar 3 with Windows 10, i7, 16GB RAM, 1TB NVMe M.2 SSD and I have divided 500GB each for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10
The /root is 256 GB, the /home is 150 GB and /swap is 35GB

Don't know if the above information helps but I need to resolve this ASAP (I have to attend a hackathon; this laptop was purchased for that reason alone) so any help is appreciated.

P.S. There are a lot of threads with similar issues but none so far with Ubuntu 19.10 and none of the threads have any concrete solution so far.